# how to connect web page to adafruit-io cloud server

Tags: node.js, web, mqtt

I am trying to connect my web page to adafruit using MQTT and Node.js. I am able to get current feed values from adafruit using commands on command prompt. but not understanding how to use it in web page? Is there any way to connect web page to adafruit using MQTT and node.js?

Comment: Can you please explain in a lot more detail exactly what you are trying to do, it is not clear at all currently

Comment: io.adafruit.com is cloud server, i want to develop my own web page which connects and communicate to adafruit at the backend. so that my web page can send or receive values to adafruit feeds.